# Python: How to pass subarrays of array into array function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The ultimate goal of my question is that I want to generate a new array 'output' by passing the subarrays of an array into a function, where the return of the function for each subarray generates a new element into 'output'.

My input array was generated as follows:

```
aggregate_input = np.random.rand(100, 5)

input = np.split(aggregate_predictors, 1, axis=1)[0]
```

So now input appears as follows:

```
print(input[0:2])

>>[[ 0.61521025  0.07407679  0.92888063  0.66066605  0.95023826]
>> [ 0.0666379   0.20007622  0.84123138  0.94585421  0.81627862]]
```

Next, I want to pass each element of input (so the array of 5 floats) through my function 'condition' and I want the return of each function call to fill in a new array 'output'. Basically, I want 'output' to contain 100 values.

```
def condition(array):

    return array[4] < 0.5
```

How do I pass each element of input into condition without using any nasty loops?

========

Basically, I want to do this, but optimized:

```
lister = []

for i in range(100):
    lister.append(condition(input[i]))

output = np.array(lister)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a 2D array, not a nested list. There is a big difference. What are you trying to achieve? Your question is very unclear, but I think that may largely be due to a lack of consistent terminology between us.

Comment: Edit your question with A) how you actually create `greater_array` and B) some examples of what you are trying to do in your function. Use words when code fails you.

Comment: Also, an improvement down the line, your function probably does not need an `if` statement at all. `return array[4] >= 0.5` already takes on the boolean values you want. In Python `True == 1` and `False == 0`, since `bool` is a special subclass of `int`.

Comment: Apparently you're using a `numpy` array. Look at the [avaliable ways to slice arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html); your case could turn out trivial.

Comment: When you make the edits someone requests, it is a good idea to ping that person. You can always comment to your own question with the person's name preceded by a "@". So to ping me, you would put @MadPhysicist somewhere in your comment. Otherwise, I would have no way of knowing you made the edits I requested.

Comment: Why are you splitting the array in the first place if you want to vectorize?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to mix numpy arrays and lists like this. When you use lists, you are stuck with using Python loops or list comprehensions. When you use numpy arrays, you get highly optimized storage and fast vectorized operations. It's better to pick one and stick with it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't actually want to use lists and arrays, I only used that as an example of what I want my code to do. That last bit does work as intended, but its not how I want it to work. I split the array first because I need the input array as it is, but I could potentially generate the output from the aggregate_input if that would make it easier

Comment: @MichaelD. So much easier. I will draft something momentarily.

Comment: @MichaelD. BTW, is `aggregate_input` vs `aggregate_predictors` a typo in one case? If so, could you fix it?

Comment: @MichaelD. Also, did you reverse the sense of `condition` on purpose when you made your edit? The original, before edits, was phrased as `array[4] >= 0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

That initial split and index does nothing.  It just wraps the array in list, and then takes out again:

```
In [76]: x=np.random.rand(100,5)
In [77]: y = np.split(x,1,axis=1)
In [78]: len(y)
Out[78]: 1
In [79]: y[0].shape
Out[79]: (100, 5)
```

The rest just tests if the 4th element of each row is <.5:

```
In [81]: def condition(array):
    ...: 
    ...:     return array[4] < 0.5
    ...: 
In [82]: lister = []
    ...: 
    ...: for i in range(100):
    ...:     lister.append(condition(x[i]))
    ...: 
    ...: output = np.array(lister)
    ...: 
In [83]: output
Out[83]: 
array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,
        True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
       ...], dtype=bool)
```

We can do just as easily with column indexing

```
In [84]: x[:,4]<.5
Out[84]: 
array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,
        True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,
       ...], dtype=bool)
```

In other words, operate on the whole 4th column of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a very simple indexing expression very convoluted. If you read the docs for [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) very carefully, you will see that passing a second argument of 1 does absolutely nothing: it splits the array into one chunk. The following line is literally a no-op and should be removed:

```
input = np.split(aggregate_predictors, 1, axis=1)[0]
```

You have a 2D numpy array of shape `100, 5` (you can check that with `aggregate_predictors.shape`). Your function returns whether or not the fifth column contains a value less than 0.5. You can do this with a single vectorized expression:

```
output = aggregate_predictors[:, 4] < 0.5
```

If you want to find the last column instead of the fifth, use index -1 instead:

```
output = aggregate_predictors[:, -1] < 0.5
```

The important thing to remember here is that all the comparison operators are vectorized element-wise in numpy. Usually, vectorizing an operation like this involves finding the correct index in the array. You should never have to convert anything to a list: numpy arrays are iterable as it is, and there are more complex iterators available.

That being said, your original intent was probably to do something like

```
input = split(aggregate_predictors, len(aggregate_predictors), axis=0)
```

OR

```
input = split(aggregate_predictors, aggregate_predictors.shape[0])
```

Both expressions are equivalent. They split `aggregate_predictors` into a list of 100 single-row matrices.